# Absolute summability implies square summability

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-convergence

I am aware of the fact that $\ell^1(\mathbb{R})$ is a subset of $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$, but I somehow can't find a very good proof of absolute summability implying square summability across the internet.

Could you kindly verify my following intuition please:

Note that if a infinite series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$

Suppose that $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |a_n| < \infty, \text{with } a_n \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n$$

By the previous observation, $\exists$ N $\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |a_n| = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} |a_n| + \sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} |a_n|, \text{ with }
|a_n| < 1, \forall n > N$$

And likewise,

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n^2 = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n^2 + \sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} a_n^2, \text{ with }
|a_n| < 1, \forall n > N$$

i.e. The infinite sum can be split into a head (which is the finite N-th partial sum) and a tail, thus it suffices to show the convergence of the tail.

By assumption, $$\sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} |a_n| < \infty$$

Since $|a_n| < 1, \forall n > N$,

$\implies |a_n|^2 < |a_n|, \forall n > N$

Thus $$\sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} |a_n|^2 < \sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} |a_n|< \infty$$ by the comparison test.

Hence $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n^2 < \infty$$

This completes the proof. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Thank you in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: The "fact" that you are aware of is not correct.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: $L^1$ is almost never a subset of $L^2$. Consider for example $f : (0,1)\to \Bbb{R}, x \mapsto x^{-2/3}$.

Comment: Despite this misleading 'fact', is the rest of my proof correct please?

Comment: Your proof is correct. Even simpler would be to use that $|a_n|\leq \sum_k |a_k|$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Apologies that I am not familiar with measure theory. In the very first line, I meant $\ell^2$, the space of square-summable sequences, instead of $L^2$, the set of functions for which $|f(t)|^2$ is Lebesgue integrable